# Apache Superset : Unable to take screenshot for sending emails

Tags: apache-superset

I am able to send CSV files as alerts, but when try to send a chart , I am getting the error

> Failed taking a Screenshot message : process unexpectedly closed with status 255

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7Deo.png)

For me, CSV files are sending without any problem, gecko driver version is 0.29, superset installed using docker compose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways in which Alerts & Report setup can go wrong.  For this I would suggest editing your `docker-compose.yml` file (or `docker-compose-non-dev.yml` if you're running in production, not development) to use the image `2.0.0-dev` for your worker containers.  That will include a functional setup of geckodriver and headless browser (Firefox) which should avoid a lot of the headaches that come from trying to install those yourself.

If your CSV reports are sending but not reports with images, this suggests a problem with the headless browser from the worker container trying to reach the report to take a screenshot.

The images you would use are:

- `apache/superset:2.0.0` for your `superset` container
- `apache/superset:2.0.0-dev` for all other containers

The first change can happen in the `superset` part of the file:

`image: apache/superset:2.0.0`

The latter can be accomplished by changing this line near the top of the file to:

```
x-superset-image: &superset-image apache/superset:2.0.0-dev
```

Which will use that image for all other containers that aren't overridden as we did for the main `superset` container.

Comment: Hello @Sam Firke, Thank you for the reply,  I have edited my dockerfile as follows,

x-superset-image: &superset-image apache/superset:${TAG:-latest-dev}

superset:
    image: apache/superset:2.0.0

superset-worker-beat:
    image: apache/superset:2.0.0-dev

Unfortunately we are getting so many errrors and unable to even start the superset using docker-compose.

Later on my local pc, I created a virtual environment and did a fresh install, now the error is

Failed taking a screenshot Message: Argument --marionette can't be set via capabilities

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: Replace `x-superset-image: &superset-image apache/superset:${TAG:-latest-dev}` with `x-superset-image: &superset-image apache/superset:2.0.0-dev`.  Things are often broken in the latest commit image which is what you're running, that's likely causing that `--marionette` error message.

Comment: This is worked !!!!!!....Wonderful, Thank you Sam Firke, Briefly what I did was, removed all the exisitng docker containers, docker volumes, then cloned from Git, then edited the docker file ,

x-superset-image: &superset-image apache/superset:${TAG:-latest-dev} with x-superset-image: &superset-image apache/superset:2.0.0-dev

The pulled the docker containers and up, Everyhting worked as expected, not at showing any error.